# How to use ipcalc to validate IP in a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to validate an IP with bash script and if it was valid, run another command. i used **ipcalc** command. but not sure why return wrong result ... I changed **0** to **1** .. **false** .. **true** but never got **valid** 
. here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(ipcalc -cs 8.8.8.8) = 0 ]]
 then
  echo "valid"
 else
  echo "invalid"
fi
```

but this one working fine in bash script and direct command line:

```
[root@sv89]# ipcalc -cs 8.8.8.8 && echo valid || echo invalid
valid
[root@sv89]# ipcalc -cs 8.8.8.256 && echo valid || echo invalid
invalid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script you are looking for is:

```
if ipcalc -cs 8.8.8.8
 then
  echo "valid"
 else
  echo "invalid"
fi
```

It is equivalent to the command line you posted.

`$()` is command substitution. It runs the command it encloses and replaces the entire expression with the output of the command (which is not what you want).

To check the exit code of a command you just put the command in the `if` statement. This is how `if [...]` works on the systems where `[` is a symlink to the `test` external program.

Comment: could you please explain more about this: where [ is a symlink to the test external program. i cant understand this

Comment: `[` is a symlink to `/bin/test`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return value, not the value that is output to stdout.

```
#!/bin/bash
ipcalc -cs 8.8.8.8
if $?
 then
  echo "valid"
 else
  echo "invalid"
fi
```

In shell land, zero is truthy, nonzero is falsy.

Comment: `[[ 0 ]]` and `[[ 1 ]]` are both truthy, because "0" and "1" are both non-null strings (and that's what `[[ ]]` with a single word in it tests). You want something like `[[ $? -eq 0 ]]` (or just put the command itself in the `if` condition, as in @axiac's answer).